# Generate Script With If EXIST DROP But Do Not Include If Not Exists In CREATE In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I want to generate the script using **`Tasks | Generate Scripts`** with **`IF Exist Drop Stored Procedure`**.

But I don't want to include **`IF NOT EXISTS - Create Stored Procedure`** while generating Script then what should I do?

**Current**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SPNAME]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SPNAME]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME] AS' 
END
GO
```

**Required**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SPNAME]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME] AS
```

*Can anyone please help me!*

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: Any version of SQL Server

Comment: `DROP -> CREATE` could lead to losing information about permissions. `CREATE -> ALTER` is safer.

Comment: could you please share any link to get the knowledge for this, it would be really appreciated. thanks @lad2025

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct option available to do this thing.
Follow below step.

1. Generate DROP scripts for all objects.

   - Include If NOT Exists = True
   - Script DROP and CREATE = Script DROP
2. Generate CREATE scripts for all objects.

   - Include If NOT Exists = False
   - Script DROP and CREATE = Script CREATE
   - Append to File = True

2nd step will append contents of drops scripts which is generated in 1st step.

If you want to merge all files in one file then use bellow command

```
for %f in (*.sql) do type "%f" >> c:\Test\output.sql
```

## Query Options

[image: Query Options]

## Drop

[image: Drop]

## Create

[image: Create]

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the "Check for object existence" option to true and generate the drop create script. It should work for 2017 or Azure SQL DB

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server 17 it's

> Script DROP and CREATE

See:
[image]